# How to serialize/deserialize dotnet core exceptions for a client library?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In both dotnet core v3 and v5, I noticed that I cannot successfully serialize an Exception. If I try to I get this

[image]

This is due to the `System.Type` on the TargetSite.DeclaryingType property. This is in v5, but in v3 the serliazation just blows up because it hits the max depth of 32 (and increasing to 128 works but still has strange cyclical behaviors).

The situation I have seems pretty straight forward. I have an application exception like `FooNotFoundException` that I want to catch and handle in my controller like:

```
public IActionResult Test()
{
    try 
    {
        // try to do something
    }
    catch(FooNotFoundException e)
    {
        return NotFound(e);
    }
}
```

Then I have a client library that I want to basically look for status code 404 for this endpoint and then deserialize to this exception type so the consumer can handle this exception as well when this endpoint is called. Seems very straight forward and sought after in my opinion, so I'm shocked to not be able to find any native MS documentation on how to properly serialize and deserialize a basic `Exception` across network boundaries like this without having to fully implement the translation to a custom DTO.

Curious if anyone has found an elegant way to do this in .NET Core v3 or v5?

Comment: Typically, one does expose entire `Exception`s to the client, due to the sensitive nature of things like stack traces, PPI, HIPPA, etc..

Comment: Stack traces would make sense to suppress, but even just the `Message` would be valuable to have. I guess I must just have to build this solution myself and map to a DTO. I was mostly just surprised there were not best practices around doing this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was typing this on the comment but it doesn't fit...

If some basic infomation like message, helpLink,.. was a few desired things,.. how about build our own response standard ?... like this

```
// On some upper middleware catching exceptions
if (_environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                var exceptionDetail = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    {"Type", exception.GetType().ToString()},
                    {"Message", exception.Message},
                    {"StackTrace", exception.StackTrace}
                };
                foreach (DictionaryEntry data in exception.Data)
                    exceptionDetail.TryAdd(data.Key.ToString(), data.Value?.ToString());
                responseResult.Error.ExceptionDetail = exceptionDetail;
            }

            return context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseResult,
                new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                }));
```

I think it's compact enough for clients like spa to handle some detail